# Operator-overloading is defined as a function but not used as a function

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor, operator-overloading

Consider the following C++ code such that I took it from "Sololearn". I'm a beginner and I would be grateful if any one could answer. It is on operator-overloading topic.

```
  class MyClass {
 public:
  int var;
  MyClass() {}
  MyClass(int a)
  : var(a) { }

  MyClass operator+(MyClass &obj) {
   MyClass res;
   res.var= this->var+obj.var;
   return res; 
  }
};
```

When they use it in main environment they use the following code

```
int main() {
  MyClass obj1(12), obj2(55);
  MyClass res = obj1+obj2;

  cout << res.var;
}
```

My questions:

Why does MyClass has two constructors? The most important question for me is that  "operator+" has been defined like a function but when we use it in main its usage is not like a function. Why? Another different  question is that is it true to say that the + used in this line  MyClass res = obj1+obj2;  is from the Operator+?

Comment: You can have as many constructors as you want, however it makes sense to construct an instance of your class. Yes that is the syntax to overload the `+` operator, not sure what else you want to hear. And yes in your example `MyClass::operator+` is being invoked from `obj1+obj2`.

Comment: `MyClass res = obj1+obj2;` is the same as `MyClass res = obj1.operator+(obj2);`  Overloaded operator are just functions with the addition of the "expected" synax.  `operator+` being  the name of the function.

Comment: `MyClass() {}` hello undefined behaviour. Don't write code like that kids!

Comment: One question per question please, not three.

Comment: @CoryKramer: Why are you answering in the comments section?

Comment: "Why does MyClass has two constructors?" - because you gave it two constructors: `MyClass() {}
  MyClass(int a)`.. what's unclear?

Comment: @JesperJuhl: The question is _why_ did the author give it two constructors. Notice that the OP is not that author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does MyClass has two constructors?

Because that's what the person who wrote it wanted. They wanted to make it so that you can provide an initial value if you wanted, and just let it default to zero otherwise.

Unfortunately, they made a mistake, and their default constructor is broken. It should be like this:

```
MyClass() : var(0) {}
```

…otherwise the value of `var` is *indeterminate* and a program trying to read it has *undefined behaviour*.

Now you can create an object like this:

```
MyClass obj;      // uses first constructor
```

Or like this:

```
MyClass obj(12);  // uses second constructor
```

---

> "operator+" has been defined like a function but when we use it in main its usage is not like a function. Why?

Because you can. Because operators are special. C++ is designed this way. To be able to overload/define them they need to be functions, but to be *operators* they need their own syntax to use.

Note that you *can* call it like a function if you want to:

```
MyClass res = obj1.operator+(obj2);
```

…but you don't want to.

---

> is it true to say that the + used in this line MyClass res = obj1+obj2; is from the Operator+?

Yes.

---

It would be better to learn C++ from [a proper book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. Can we return another thing instead of res? Of course, I know the data type is MyClass.

Comment: @Baghban: As long as it's a `MyClass` you can return whatever you like. Although people have certain expectations regarding how operator functions behave, and don't like to be surprised by them doing strange things. So try not to stray too far from what yours is doing at the moment.

Comment: I deleted the first constructor `MyClass(): var(0) {}` and got an error. Why?

Comment: @Baghban: Because now the statement `MyClass res;` has no way to work.

Comment: (`MyClass res(this->var+obj.var);` probably would have been better)